# Is there any way to control volume on ISD1600B?

Tags: audio

I'm using the [ISD1610B](http://www.nuvoton.com/hq/enu/ProductAndSales/ProductLines/AudioApplicationIC/ISDVoiceIC/ISDChipCorder/Documents/ISD1600B.pdf) chip and I would like add some volume control on the Speaker/Buzzer or on the optional speaker.

[image]

Can I add a potentiometer at the SP+ or SP- line? But wouldn't that only let me go down to 1/2 volume since it is a differential output? Any other suggestions?

EDIT:
I'm looking to adjust the volume of the speaker used for playback, not the input volume from the microphone (this can be adjusted using the AGC pin as Leon pointed out below).

Answer (score 1):

Varying the voltage on the AGC pin should do it, according to the data sheet. It will vary the microphone amplifier gain.

[image]

Comment: I see. The reason I asked was because I did not quite understand how to use this pin from the description. The application circuit shows a capacitor, so where would I put the resistor (series, parallel)? Would I replace it with the voltage divider from a potentiomter?

Comment: Just connect the pot slider to the AGC pin. You still need the capacitor, of course.

Comment: @LeonHeller Can you add a schematic?

Comment: @LeonHeller I just realized this doesn't actually solve my problem. This controls the volume at the input during recording, but I'm looking for volume control of the buzzer during playback. I added an edit above.